# elementary 5.0 boot problem on macbook 2,1 (late 2006)

Tags: boot, macbook, intel

The original iso-file from elementary webpage doesn't work for installation, so i have successfully installed with iso from https://mattgadient.com/2016/07/11/linux-dvd-images-and-how-to-for-32-bit-efi-macs-late-2006-models/.

After installation boot stops by "changing to intel from vesa vsg". Only rescue is to power off the macbook. Curiosly after second boot try, everything is ok and the Desktop appears.

At the next shutdown and boot, same problem: boot stops.
Hard Reset, then boot ok.

I'm confused…
Does anybody have an idea what to do to fix this?

Thank you, and sorry for my bad english, im from Germany.